# What kind of food does God eat?

Tags: gods, vedic-gods

Do gods eat their own creations; Do they have any appetite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At spiritual level, God need not literally "eat" the food in human appetite sense. But as a devotee, out of love one offers food to the god in order to remember him. God even in their material form also consumes whatever is offered to them with true love and devotion. For example, below thread discusses, how a simple "bitten rice" was enough for Krishna to be gratified towards Sudama:
[Why did Rukmini stop Lord Krishna from eating beaten rice given by Sudama a second time?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2598/1049)

We should offer (& eat) ***Sattvik* food** to the [demi]gods, because the nature of *Sattva* is closest to the God. Below is the general guideline for the *Sattvik* foods:

> [BG 17.8](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/17) — Foods dear to those in
>   the mode of goodness increase the duration of life, purify one’s
>   existence and give strength, health, happiness and satisfaction. Such
>   foods are juicy, fatty, wholesome, and pleasing to the heart.

<sub>In one of the interesting event of Mahabharata, during forest exile of 13 years, sage Durvasa & his follower Brahmins pay surprise visit to Paandavas. All the food was already consumed and hence Draupadi was not having any chances of serving the food. Krishna arrives at the last moment and eats just 1 leftover morsel of rise and with his *Yoga maya*, he makes all the Rishis content with food and saves the day.</sub>

Comment: plus one for God need not literally "eat" the food in human appetite sense that you mention, But I think  BG 17.8 here Krishna Describe Features of Sattvik food , that human should eat, But as a God he don't need to eat but with love  he only accept a leaf, a ﬂower, a fruit or water that he Mention Bg 9.26.  I also agree as Human form God accept everything  that human should eat.

Comment: @BhavinChhatrola, In those times mostly people were financially well-off, at least the *Kshatriya*s like Arjuna. But Krishna stresses on love rather than material. So actually the BG 9.26 suggests that lord *even* accepts leaf, flower, fruit & water, if served with love. Otherwise just think, if those are the only 4 items, then how about so many genuine people offering coconut & milk to Shivalinga, or 56-bhogas to Thakorji, laddoos to Ganesha & various other items to various demigods. There are traditions in various sects where people offer all food for lunch to God 1st before they consume.

Comment: "There are traditions in various sects where people offer all food for lunch to God 1st before they consume"  because  Krishna says in [Bg 3.13 ][(http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/3/13) ] The devotees of the Lord are released from all kinds of sins because they eat food which is offered ﬁrst for sacriﬁce. Others, who prepare food for personal sense enjoyment, verily eat only sin.

Comment: @BhavinChhatrola, translations by Prabhupada are often erroneous. The one you linked is 1 of the classic examples. Worse that he even locked all his writings for any future alterations even done in good spirit. So ISCKON has found a good way of keeping the "word by word translation" for slokas. There is no word as "offer" in that sloka. The actual meaning is *"Devotees who eat after Yajna are relieved from all sins, but those eat sin who prepare food for sense enjoyment"*. In this context, I explained the meaning of terms "demigods" & "Yajna" in http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8553/1049.

Comment: @BhavinChhatrola, we often see the meaning of *Yajna* as Sacrifice, i.e. *Hom-havan* & *Kriya Kanda*, but it's not all. For Karmayogis or Gyanyogis such things may not be relevant. All has to do *Yajna*. The actual meaning of *Yajna* is "perseverance"(*Parishrama*). The demigods are elements of nature. Now you try to get sense of BG 3.13. If one eats after doing duty would be relieved of the sins of harming plants or whatever they consume, because they consume food to retain themselves. So that again they can perform duties towards *Devata*s. Notice that all the *Deva*s are elements of nature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30430/discussion-between-iammilind-and-bhavin-chhatrola).

Answer (score 2):

In Geeta lord Krishna Says

> patraṁ puṣpaṁ phalaṁ toyaṁ yo me bhaktyā prayacchati tad ahaṁ
>   bhakty-upahṛtam aśnāmi prayatātmanaḥ [Bg 9.26]
>
> If one offers Me with love and devotion a leaf, a ﬂower, a fruit or
>   water, I will accept it.

[Bg 9.26](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/9/26)

Its Clearly mention by lord Krishna he will accept a leaf, a ﬂower, a fruit or water