# Who is Krishna's friend Vijaya?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, arjuna

In [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m14/m14069.htm) of the Ashwamedha Parva of the Mahabharata, Krishna brings Abhimanyu's son Parikshit back to life, after he is born stillborn as a result of Ashwatthama's Brahmastra (which I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2390/36)).  Here is what Krishna says in order to bring the boy back to life:

> Never before have I uttered an untruth even in jest. Never have I turned back from battle. (By the merit of those acts) let this child revive! As righteousness is dear to me, as Brahmanas are specially dear to me, (by the merit of that disposition of mine) let Abhimanyu's son, who is born dead, revive! **Never hath a misunderstanding arisen between me and my friend Vijaya.** Let this dead child revive by that truth! As truth and righteousness are always established in me, let this dead child of Abhimanyu revive (by the merit of these)! As Kansa and Kesi have been righteously slain by me, let this child revive today by that truth!

My question who is this "Vijaya" who was the friend of Krishna?  Vijaya means victory, so I'm guessing that it refers to Arjuna.  Another friend of Krishna was Sudama (whom I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2603/36)), but I doubt he would be called Vijaya.

Are there any commentaries on the Mahabharata that address who Krishna is referring to here?

Comment: Vijaya is a common name for Arjuna.

Comment: Besides,  Vijayasakha, Vijaya**sarathi** are common names of Krsna.

Comment: [Vijayawada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vijayawada) = Vijaya (Arjuna) + wada (place), literally place of Arjuna or place established by Arjuna at foot hills of [Indrakeela mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanaka_Durga_Temple) on banks of river Krishna. After getting Pasupatastra, Arjuna asked Shiva to manifest and  Shiva manifested as "**VIJAYESWARA**" (after Vijaya or Arjuna) at foothills of Indrakeeladri hill.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Vijaya is the one of the ten names of Arjuna. In the [Virata Parva of Mahabharata, SECTION XLIV](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m04/m04044.htm), Arjuna has told his ten names to Uttara (Son of Virata) described as below:

> Arjuna said, 'I will, O son of Virata, tell thee my ten names. Listen thou and compare them with what thou hadst heard before. Listen to them with close attention and concentrated mind. They are Arjuna, Falguna, Jishnu, Kiritin, Swetavahana, Vibhatsu, **Vijaya**, Krishna, Savyasachin and Dhananjaya.

And Arjuna is a well known friend of Krishna as told by Arjuna in [Srimad Bhagavad Gita](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/11):

> Bg 11.41-42 — Thinking of You as my friend, I have rashly addressed You “O Kṛṣṇa,” “O Yādava,” “**O my friend**,” not knowing Your glories. Please forgive whatever I may have done in madness or in love. I have dishonored You many times, jesting as we relaxed, lay on the same bed, or sat or ate together, sometimes alone and sometimes in front of many friends. O infallible one, please excuse me for all those offenses.

So, in my opinion **Shri Krishna is clearly talking about Arjuna**.

Comment: Good Answer. Vijayawada is named after Vijaya (Arjuna) when he got Pasupatastra from Lord Shiva.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Thanks. I have just read your comment below the question. It is also a very helpful information.